# Angular: Best way to pass data to a component (object vs many arguments)

Tags: angular, angular-components

I'm wondering which of the following is better

```
<my-component [data]="settings"></my-component>
```

or

```
<my-component 
    [bar]="settings.foo.bar"
    [baz]=settings.baz"></my-component>
```

And the settings  object would then look like this

```
this.settings = {
    foo: { bar: 10 }
    baz: 2
};
```

The first form is compact, but less explicit about what `my-component` needs. I can image that there are situation in which it could be better to pass whole objects to a component (if there are too many properties for example). And what about performance. I can image that change detection is harder and less performant if you pass around whole objects. Any help/tips regarding this subject would be appreciated!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Refactoring Angular components from many inputs/outputs to a single config object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47743281/refactoring-angular-components-from-many-inputs-outputs-to-a-single-config-objec)

Answer (score 3):

I think specifying individual values is a better approach. As you wrote, it's more explicit about what you need, and you can specify the values from other sources (not just the settings object). This way, change detection is easy and your component can be optimized by using

```
@Component({  
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
```

Using the `OnPush` strategy, Angular will skip the change detection for the component's subtree if none of its input values changed.

For more info see

- https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/02/22/angular-2-change-detection-explained.html
- https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2017/02/02/making-your-angular-app-fast.html

Answer (score 2):

As far as my experience is concerned, the priority in front end software development today should be on code readability. As in terms of performances the difference is neglectable, I would opt for the first option, where you clearly pass a single `settings` object. When reading the .html page, there is no interest in digging in further here; the 'reader' can see the structure of your variable somewhere else in the script.

Answer (score 1):

Better option is first. HTML code is more concise, when someone will need to find out what is settings, then no problem jump to ts file. Typescript 
types are a good way to identify objects, so you don't need to pass properties separately.